# Can we access iPhone contact?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.3

I met a lot of new people. I want to know which contact I recently called, messaged, or added.

Well, there is no app for that. So I am going to make one.

Is it possible? Do we have API for that?

Comment: I strongly doubt that, this sounds like it'd potentially be a major privacy violation. Even address book access requires a confirmation dialog after a few privacy hooplas.

Comment: I'm making an application that involves accessing the contacts of the user. What kind of confirmation dialog do I need to display?

Comment: I dont think you do have the access to anything except the contacts, i never heard of creation dates or so

Comment: @qegal I *think* the OS pops up the confirmation dialog automatically when your app tries to touch contacts, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith: The docs mention creation and modification date properties: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW3

Comment: @millimoose however I think that it is for only contacts which the app has added - 'The value of these constants is undefined until one of the following functions has been called: ABAddressBookCreate, ABPersonCreate, ABGroupCreate.'

Comment: @jonathanlking That says "of these constants", not "of these properties". My gut tells me this wording just means those three functions run some one-time initialisation code; if the properties themselves were unavailable I'd have worded the documentation differently.

Comment: I might have completely misinterpreted what you just said, but dates _are_ constants - as the date something was created will never change, but will also not exist until it is created.

Comment: Well, along time ago I can synchronize contact to my outlook and outlook can sort those contacts based on date. I can't do that anymore.

Comment: @jonathanlking So you believe it's more likely the documentation page uses "constant" to refer to the values of properties that you can fetch using the constants listed in the documentation page? Instead of referring to *the constants documented on said page*?